# Help with CakePHP adding new page

Tags: php, cakephp

I'm redesigning site that use CakePHP, and till now everything goes well because I just update pages, change content of page already set, but now I need new page...
And I don't know how to add...

There is a page that have layout that I need on my new page, site now use link like: **http://site.com/pages/30**, but I want to create new page that use **same** layout ( **same** top/bottom headers, **same** panel on right side, everything to be as it is, but just to change main part of page, and create NEW ( not change this one ) link **http://site.com/logo**

I know PHP perfectly, but this CakePHP is killing me... It's very difficult to work with CakePHP when you know PHP, it's totally different point of view but almost same thing...

I already have code for that middle part created, but I need to create this new link, use layout from this page, and insert it...

Can anyone help me with creating this?

If you can write step-by-step how to do this, I will really appreciate that...
Where can I find files that control this, how to add new, and etc...

Please

Comment: A new page is a new function in your controller and a new view template file. A common design that wraps your content is a layout. I suggest you read the CakePHP documentation and go through one of its tutorials.

Comment: What is "my controller" ? Where can I find file where I write that function? Okay, so I won't create new layout file, I will use same, just create new view file? How can I connect those later? I was reading and it's all to complicated, and I need ONLY to add new link and new page... With PHP it's so easy, but this...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Cakephp you have got layout files (under views/layouts) and this layout file (eg. Default.ctp) is your main template. The view from a controller is loaded in this template.

Link:
In Cakephp you can name links under the directory config in the fileroutes.php. Look in this file. It´s very easy.

For new pages you can build for example an article controller where you can create your new pages (with the specific layout file)...

But you can start with the blog tutorial or read the handbook of cakephp.

Comment: That is what I needed... routes.php is name of file... THANK YOU! Now I know where I should start from... Thank you soooo much!!!

Comment: @Mika the link is broken

Comment: @VinGarcia Thanks.